# Numbering with non-italic

Tags: numbering, italic

In the theorem environment, I use `\begin{enumerate}[(i)]` to list some properties. This makes the numbering italic but I want them to be regular font. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: See the enumitem package.

Comment: bravo for realizing that enumeration indices should be upright, regardless of the environment.  so many people don't.